# Visual Studio 6 C++ running in Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-8.1, visual-studio-6

MSDEV.exe (Visual Studio C++ 6.0) crash in windows 8.1.
Renaming to MSDEV2.exe and work perfectly

Reasons?

Comment: Re the off topic vote: please read the description "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming": Visual Studio is primarily used for programming.

Comment: Renaming it probably prevents several appcompat shims from doing their job.  That does *not* mean it will work better.  VS6 is 4 Windows versions past its expiration date, only ever consider running it in a VM that boots XP or less.

Comment: Yes, VS6 is a very old compiler, but some old projects are running with this and if a client need a little change in your code, is not time-efficient to start a VM to run a VS6. Also, the code generated by this lightweight compiler, run in all windows version correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reasons?

VC++6 is pushing two decades old, first used against Windows NT 4: 6 versions ago. That it can run at all is a surprise.

With details of the crash (eg. a stack dump) any more would be a pure guess.

Comment: I agree that the dump file, it could give more information.
I am trying to generate the dump file, but the system does not generate any, or given the option to save. I keep trying.